# Saving Items from Listbox to SQL Server table using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq

I have the following Item(s) A (string) and Item(s) B (decimal) In my WPF ListBox. I intend to
to save them to a table in MS SQL database with the respective data type.

```
  DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
 foreach (var items in MyListBox.Items)
       { 
            //I was thinking in this terms but I doubt if its the correct code
           items=MyListBox.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();

            //
            //Then use this Linq Statement to insert the data
            Student std = new Student();
            std.Name=items
            std.Marks=items
            dc.Student.InsertOnSubmit(std);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Any clarifications needed please ask, I am still a leaner in C#, wpf, Linq

Comment: Are you using Linq2SQL (DBContext etc.) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's an algorithm to create a list of Students from the contents of your ListBox. There is no error checking here so you'll have to handle that later depending on your needs. I'll give a little explanation at the bottom.

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
double dub = 0;
items = MyListBox.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
     if (i % 2 == 0)
     {
         dub = double.Parse(items[i]);
     }
     else
     {
         Student s = new Student();
         s.Name = items[i];
         s.Marks = dub;
         students.Add(s);
     }
}
```

Alright so here is how it works. Outside of the loop I allocate a list of students, we'll need that to hold the unknown number students coming from the listbox. I used a for loop rather than a for each so that I can use the mod operator to check whether the value is the double or the string. Doubles should come first so I'm holding that in a temp variable. If it's a double I parse it and assign the result to dub. Because we're dealing with pairs if i % 2 != 0 then the current item is a name, that's why I'm safe using an else block. In the else block I allocate a new student object and set the name with the current item. Then I set the marks with my cached double. At that point I can just add it to the list. Alternatively in the else block you could use a constructor that accepts a double and a string and does the assignment. We'll know both values at that point so that would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks @evanmcdonnal The Link will be helpful, I have added the missing codes

Comment: @MichaelGoyote you're still missing code that actually creates a connection the database. If you're using the SQLConnector you'll see it when you initialize the object, passing it a connection string. Then you prepare a command, and then you execute. Those couple lines of code are something you might have at to actually do an insert with EF but that assumes you already have a model set up and you've initialized the context ect. From what I can tell there is no context in the scope of that method.

Comment: I believe you asking about the connection string, I have some other forms which I am able to perform CRUD functions, so connection to the DB is not an issue, but getting the the two items of different data types from the Listbox.

Comment: @MichaelGoyote if you can provide more information about what the contents of that List will be I'll write the code to transform it into a list of Students. I just need some information like will every even value be the string and every odd value be the double?

Comment: There are two List boxes, List box A is populated from SQL using this query  var items = from r in dc.Students select r;              lstBoxA.ItemsSource = items;
    Table in SQL has the following fields StudentID, StudentName,StudentMarks

The user then selects the student(s) s/he want to move to ListBox B. Now the Students and their marks in List B are then Inserted Into a different table. Challenge is Taking the List of Students from List Box B and Inserting them into the SQL different table

Comment: Yes the even value to be the double and odd value to be string.

Comment: @MichaelGoyote Alright, I've edited with logic to create a list of students from a list of strings (the contents of your ListBox).

Comment: I have tried the solutions you suggested, what data type should assign to items....items = MyListBox.Items.Cast<String>().ToList(). var doesn't work returns this error "Unable to cast object of type 'ProjectName.Student' to type 'System.String'."

Comment: @MichaelGoyote omg all you need to do is `List<Student> students = MyListBox.Items.ToList();` they items in the list are already of type student so all of that code is needless.